# Timepicker Restriction Current Time

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, timepicker

Hi I have used datePicker and set minDate to 0 to restrict access to past dates.

Now I am trying to use timepicker and restrict access to previous times being selected, it is as easy as just passing in one value like for datePicker, or do I need to do more.

I am not great at writing javascript so if someone could show me a solution if its complicated, do I need to get current hour and current min first and how do i then restrict the timepicker to just show times after this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this ??

```
$('#timepicker').timepicker({
    onHourShow: function( hour ) { 
        var currenttime = new Date();
        if ( $('#datepicker').val() == $.datepicker.
                                  formatDate ( 'mm/dd/yy', currenttime ) ) {
            if ( hour <= currenttime.getHours() ) {
                alert('nope');
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: Yeah I am able to get the current time so that it highlights the current hour and minute in the GUI. But it still allows previous hours and minutes to be selected how can I disable them?